# ActiveRecord / Arel: How to query self joined table (from has_many relation)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel, squeel

I'm trying to convert some code from Squeel to ActiveRecord / Arel. The models looks like this:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :institution
  belongs_to :issuer

  has_many :related_contracts, :through => :issuer, :source => :contracts
end

class Institution < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_one :contract, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Issuer < ActiveRecord:Base
  has_many :contracts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And the code i am trying to rewrite, in Contract:

```
def self.foo
  joins {[institution, issuer.institution]}
  .where { |db| db.last_date >= db.related_contracts.last_date }
end
```

I can convert the `joins` and `>=` operator inside the where query using ActiveRecord and Arel respectively. However, I do not know how I can reference the equivalent of `db.related_contracts` using either of the two syntaxes (since i can't call `arel_table` on RelatedContract as it isn't a class).

EDIT:
This is the closest i have so far:

```
  def self.foo
    fc = Contract.arel_table
    rc = Arel::Table.new(:related_contracts)
    joins(:institution, :related_contracts => :institution)
    .where(fc[:last_date].gteq(rc[:last_date]))
  end
```

But the where condition is using `[related_contracts].[last_date]` instead of `[related_contracts_contracts].[last_date]`

Does anyone have any ideas? I *really* do not want to resort to writing raw SQL strings. I think these are related:
[How to get the arel table of a habtm association?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747284/how-to-get-the-arel-table-of-a-habtm-association)
[Convert ActiveRecord habtm query to Arel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420773/convert-activerecord-habtm-query-to-arel/13445889#13445889)

Using Rails 3.2.12

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your other models too just so that the relationship between them is clear.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for looking

Comment: I would question why you don't have to write any raw SQL.  For your purposes `>=` operator, that is fully portable across rdbms's.  It feels like trying to force yourself into the AREL box is just causing unnecessary headaches.